# Incorrect syntax when attempting to use two values in order to create a parameter in SSRS

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I'm attempting to create a parameter for when `jodrtg.fdescnum <> inmastx.fbin1`. I want to be able to use this in a dropdown list selection for my report. I have tried a number of combinations but keep getting syntax errors near the `<`or `=`.I'd be appreciative if anyone can point me in the right direction. I've never tried using two fields to create a single parameter before.
This what I've been attempting to get as my final result.

`jodrtg.fdescnum <> inmastx.fbin1 = @MoldPress`

Comment: Is this an expression for a  filter criteria?

Comment: @RossBush Yes, it's going in the `WHERE clause` of my DataSet

Comment: Is @MoldPress a parameter with a Boolean datatype?

Comment: @RossBush Yes it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I learned that you can only use one operator at a time but they can be combined using bool logic.
`WHERE (jodrtg.fdescnum <> inmastx.fbin1 
OR @ParameterName = 'Unfiltered')`

Answer (score -1):

```
AND (jodrtg.fdescnum <> inmastx.fbin1) OR @MoldPress = 0
```

Comment: Please provide some more explanation on your answer.